# How do i explode slice from pie chart using Bokeh?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh

Here is a piece of python code using matplotlib library for plotting pie-chart and exploding slice from chart

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
values = [12, 55, 4, 32, 14]
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'm']
labels = ['India', 'US', 'UK', 'Poland', 'China']
explode = [0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0]
plt.pie(values, colors = colors, labels = labels, explode = explode)
plt.show()
```

[Like This one i want to create/plot pie chart using Bokeh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP8AT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Bokeh `0.12.4` there is nothing built in the core library to do that. You could certainly draw such a chart using the [`wedge`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure.wedge) glyph method, and drawing the individual wedges yourself. Then you could offset the center of one of the wedges to "explode" it:

```
from math import pi

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

p = figure(x_range=(-1.2, 1.2), y_range=(-1.2, 1.2))

p.wedge(x=0 , y=0, radius=1, start_angle=0, end_angle=0.75*pi, color="red")
p.wedge(x=0 , y=0, radius=1, start_angle=0.75*pi, end_angle=1.05*pi, color="blue")
p.wedge(x=0 , y=0, radius=1, start_angle=1.05*pi, end_angle=1.55*pi, color="green")

# "explode" one wedge by offsetting its center
p.wedge(x=0.1 , y=-0.1, radius=1, 
        start_angle=1.55*pi, end_angle=2*pi, color="orange")


output_file("foo.html")

show(p)
```

which results in

[image]

If you'd like this to be a built in feature to Bokeh, please consider making a feature request issue on the [project issue tracker](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues).